# Cant read cookies from custom dev domain

Tags: laravel, nginx, webpack

I want to work locally and I've set in the hosts file

127.0.0.1 dev.domain.com

the dev.domain.com subdomain is not set in the nginx config on the live server, only in my local hosts file

I've started the dev server (webpack) with self signed ssl and made the certificate as trusted, so now it appears with green in the browser bar as a Valid certificate would

So now I'm viewing the locally runned app on https://dev.domain.com and I see all the cookies from www.domain.com and .domain.com in chrome devtools

The problem is that when I do an ajax call and dump the cookies from php, none of them appear for dev.domain.com but all appear for www.domain.com

Comment: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/set-cookies-on-root-domain

Comment: the cookies are set for .domain.com .. shouldn't they be able to be read from either dev.domain.com or from domain.com?

Comment: not by default afaik